# How do I simulate The Button on Reddit with Python?

Tags: python

For those of you who don't know, the Button was a social experiment on Reddit that had a button that would expire within a minute if left unpressed. Every press of the button would restart the timer. Any help with this question is greatly appriciated!

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you want to re-implement The Button with python? If so with what framework you want to work or what platform is your target.

please share more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you tagged python. I guess you need javascript to do what you want.

In JS you could do something like this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
let timer = 0;

const counter = setInterval(() => {
   timer += 1;
   if (timer >= 60) {
     button.parentElement.removeChild(button);
   }
}, 1000);

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  timer = 0;
});
```

```html
<a class="button">Hello World</a>
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful. asrah wants to re-implement it as a python application.

Answer (score 0):

You would have some some sort of input function, eg. the press of the enter button.
But beforehand you would have registered a timeout which would kill the input after n=60 seconds.

In python3 it could look like this:

```
from signal import alarm
from signal import signal
from signal import SIGALRM
from time import sleep

def handler(signum, frame):
    print("\n\nNo more button pressing!")
    raise Exception("end of time")

def loop_forever():
    while 1:
        alarm(60)
        input("hit enter, before a minute runs out!")
        print("good job. Once again!")
        alarm(0)

signal(SIGALRM, handler)

try:
    loop_forever()
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
```